# StringFormat formatting in xaml for currency

Tags: wpf, xaml, string-formatting

I am using the following code `Binding Path=InvoiceAmount, StringFormat={}{0:C0}`snippet and its working good, as i am not interested in the fraction part. It yields the result in this manner **$12**. But for sake of reading, can the currency format be like this **$12.00** instead of above.

I mean any rounding-off code for decimal part or any hack for such situation

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Any Binding can be "hacked" using IValueConverter ;)

You may use format like this `Binding Path=InvoiceAmount, StringFormat={}{0:C0}.00`, but be careful, because this way dont care about system decimal separator.

Comment: how to show the currency at the end not at the beginning ?

Answer (score 31):

In the application I work on, we use the following and it displays $12.00

```
StringFormat='{}{0:c}'
```

Cheers

Comment: How to change it for different currency?

Comment: You can specify the currencyby using ToString as described there: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx#CFormatString

Answer (score 6):

```
Text="{Binding Price, StringFormat='c'}"
```

Comment: worked for my use case, but he wanted it to ignore the cents and always show `.00`